# fscanf fails to read data from txt file

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to run my code on eclipse with ubuntu.

I have dumped the data using fprintf into one txt file and reading that file by using fscanf. I am not able to read that values into data array.

Below is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */

int main(){
    char* data;
    FILE *fp;
    size_t result;
    data = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*(1280*800));//Size of one frame
    if (data==NULL){
        printf("NOt able to allocate memory properly\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    fp = fopen ("\\home\\studinstru\\Desktop\\filedump.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Error in creating dump file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    for(int m = 0;m<1280;m++){
         for(int n = 0;n<800;n++){
         fscanf(fp,"%d/t",data[m*800 + n]);
     }
   }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my filedump.txt data :

```
79  78  78  77  78  79  81  95
82  81  81  81  82  82  82  82
79  78  78  77  78  79  81  95
82  81  81  81  82  82  82  82
79  78  78  77  78  79  81  95
82  81  81  81  82  82  82  82 ....
```

Can you tell what is wrong in this?

Comment: Try flushing and closing file.

Comment: If this is C, then you should not cast the result of `malloc`. If this is C++, you should use `std::string` and (generally) C++ I/O. In other words, C != C++ and you should generally tag only the language you are writing / compiling.

Comment: what is the meaning of flushing and closing ?

Comment: What is the meaning of `fprintf(fp,"\n");` on a read-only file?

Comment: "error in creating dump file" is a (mostly) useless error message.  Try: `fp=open(path,mode);  if(fp==NULL) {perror(path); exit(1);}`  (and use EXIT_FAILURE instead of '1')

Comment: @WilliamPursell,error is not opening dump file ..file is opening properly bt data is zero only after fscanf ...it has to show that data as like the dump.txt data what I have mentioned in my query

Comment: @studinstru, I am aware that the question you are asking is not related to the file open.  You are not aware that you are handling the error incorrectly.  error messages belong on stderr and ought to inform the user of the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couble of problems

1. Your `fscanf()` format is wrong and you are passing the value instead of it's address, you should use

   ```
   fscanf(fp, "%d", &data[n + 800 * m]);
   ```

   if you meant `"\t"` whcih is the `tab` character, it's not needed anyway and passing the value instead of it's address is Undefined Behavior, because `fscanf()` will treat the value as a pointer, and it's not likely pointing to a valid memory address, moreover, it's unintialized which is another reason for undefined behavior.
2. You declared `data` as `char *data` and store `int`'s in it, that is also Undefined Behavior.
3. You must check the return value of `fscanf()` beacuse if it fails, then the value will be uninitialized and there will be once again, Undefined Behavior and also you are going to read past the end of the file because you will never know if you reached it.
4. You are writing into the file and you open it for reading, this

   ```
   fprintf(fp, "\n");
   ```

   is wrong, you don't need it to read from the file.
5. [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495) though this is not causing problems in this case, it will improve the quality of your code.
6. Don't use `sizeof(char)` it makes your code harder to read and it's completely unnecessary since the standard mandates that `sizeof(char) == 1`.
7. You don't need the nested loop to read the data, because the shape of the data is irrelevant since `fscanf()` ignores all whitespace characters.

   It is sufficient to read throug the file and use a counter to move through the array, at the end you can check how many values where read to verify the integrity of the data.

This is a fixed version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */

int main()
{
    FILE  *fp;
    size_t index;
    int   *data;

    data = malloc(1280 * 800);
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        printf("NOt able to allocate memory properly\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fp = fopen("\\home\\studinstru\\Desktop\\filedump.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in creating dump file\n");
        free(data);

        return 2;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &data[index]) == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d ", data[index]);
        index += 1;
        if (index % 800 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: I recommend the use of compiler warnings, they would help prevent silly mistakes and some other mistakes like `char *data` and reading `int`'s into it.

Also, from your file path `"\\home\\studinstru\\Desktop\\filedump.txt"` it seems you are on a non-windows system, and very likely the directory separator is `/` instead of `\`, so the correct path has to be

```
"/home/studinstru/Desktop/filedump.txt"
```

Comment: @studinstru Your program has more problems.

Comment: @studinstru check the answer, I didn't find more problems in the code, if you fix this, it must work.

Comment: for me     while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &data[index]) == 1) condition is failing

Comment: @studinstru no, it might be the data file issue, but now you see why you **must** check the return value of functions, it's certainly not eclipse, although in my opinion eclipse is too heavy for such a simple program, what operating system are you using?

Comment: @studinstru What desktop? if it's not `KDE` install [geany](http://www.geany.org/).

Comment: ,now I am able to read the data .I got the solution .I had opened the eclipse through docker and trying to access the dump.txt which is outside the docker .So during first attempt I have opend that file by using append mode .SO one dummy file with zero byte created and that same is giving zero results in data .When I changed that file to docker,I am able to get the result .Thanks all for your reply .

Comment: @studinstru wierd filename if you are on a linux system, directory separator is `/` not ``\``. And your `fopen()` should have returned `NULL` giving you the correct error message. Check why did that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
fscanf(fp,"%d/t",data[m*800 + n]);
```

with

```
fscanf(fp,"%d/t",&data[m*800 + n]);
```

`fscanf()` needs address of destination variable as argument and not the variable itself.

Also I am not getting why are doing this:

`fprintf(fp,"\n");`

Comment: No luck ..I already tried with & , but still i am not able to see no update in data variable in watch window .it is having zero value only .

Comment: have you checked in eclipse ...I think there should be some thing I have to so in eclipse to run ..I think in VS it will work bt nt in eclipse

Comment: my mistake i can remove fprintf ..sorry for that ,,bt still having same issue

Comment: @studinstru try with my answer, you have mor issues.

Comment: @iharob,with your code , while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &data[index]) == 1) condition is failing for me .is it eclipse issue ??